# Ajax POST request in JSON doesn't work

Tags: ajax, http, post, request

I try to send an HTTP POST request from ajax to PHP, but I have a syntax error that I don't understand..
Is there anyone who can help me ?

**index.php**

```
            var key = "keytest";

            $.ajax({                                      
                url: 'requests.php',       
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '{"uniqueKey" : '+key+'}',
                success:function( rep ) {
                    $('#content').html(rep.content);
                },
                error:function(a,b,err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
```

**requests.php**

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

$uniqueKey = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'uniqueKey');
$key = "newKey";
$retour = array('key' => $key);
echo json_encode($retour);
```

Comment: This bit doesn't look right data: '{"uniqueKey" : '+key+'}', maybe data: '{"uniqueKey" : "'+key+'"}'. But, also, what is the error?

Comment: I've also the same problem with :  '{"uniqueKey" : "'+key+'"}' .

SyntaxError
message: "Unexpected token E"
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token E↵    at Object.parse (native)↵    at e.extend.parseJSON (http://5.39.76.144:803/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2:10821)↵    at cb (http://5.39.76.144:803/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2:1373)↵    at w (http://5.39.76.144:803/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4:12340)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.d (http://5.39.76.144:803/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4:18318)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't build JSON by hand, use `JSON.stringify`

```
data: JSON.stringify({uniqueKey: key}),
```

Php does not populate `$_POST`(INPUT_POST) when the request body is JSON, only for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`
To get json you'll have to read it from `php://input`

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$uniqueKey = $obj->uniqueKey;
```

Also you code only responds with a `key` value but the ajax request expects a `content` value. You should change the dataType to text to see if you get back what you expect.

```
        $.ajax({                                      
            url: 'requests.php',       
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: JSON.stringify({uniqueKey: key}),
            success:function( rep ) {
                $('#content').html(rep);
            },
            error:function(a,b,err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```